# Pandas: sum next 5 items of dataframe after some specific item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame which looks like just a list of numbers:

| original | option 1 | option 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| -1 | NaN | 9 |
| 4 | NaN | NaN |
| -1 | NaN | 15 |
| 6 | 9 | NaN |
| 7 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 15 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN |
| 0 | NaN | NaN |

I need to sum next 3 values of df after each negative value - see "option1" or "option2" columns.
If will also work if I get only sum results, i.e. a separate data structure which would look like [9, 15].

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'original': {0: 1, 1: -1, 2: 4, 3: -1, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

n = 3

df['option 1'] = (df['original'].rolling(n).sum()
                  .where(df['original'].shift(n).lt(0))
                  )
                  
df['option 2'] = df['option 1'].shift(-n)

print(df)

   original  option 1  option 2
0         1       NaN       NaN
1        -1       NaN       9.0
2         4       NaN       NaN
3        -1       NaN      15.0
4         6       9.0       NaN
5         7       NaN       NaN
6         2      15.0       NaN
7         3       NaN       NaN
8         0       NaN       NaN
```

**Explanation**

- First, use [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to create a rolling window for applying `sum`.
- Next, chain [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and set the `cond` parameter to an evaluation of values less than zero ([`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)) for a shifted ([`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)) version of column `original`.
- For `option 2` we simply apply a negative shift on `option 1`.